# c# error The type or namespace name 'SampleMain' does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, .net

> Error 7   The type or namespace name
>   'SampleMain' does not exist in the
>   namespace
>   'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Utilities'
>   (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

i am getting this error on this line:

```
        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Utilities.SampleMain.MainForm mainForm = (System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Utilities.SampleMain.MainForm)this.ParentForm;
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need help figuring out the 'structure' of the namespaces, use the Object Browser from within Visual studio or use Reflector to view what's within the

`System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Utilities`

namespace.  This may help you gain an understanding as to what you can and cannot access within each.

Answer (score 2):

I get this error when I have no reference to the library in the "References" folder in my project. Check and make sure you are referencing it by clicking on the + next to the References folder and expanding the list.

Some of the libraries require you to explicitly reference them, even if they are contained in a namespace you are already referencing.

Edit: Also, make sure that the namespace/class you are trying to use really exists.

Edit: 'SampleMain' may not even be a good object to use. Found this that suggests that you shouldn't reference sample environment classes: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/MSWinWebChart/thread/26aac6f7-d3bf-492f-bb52-dc88477f1b1b

Comment: i have this referenced 'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization, however i cannot reference this class System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Utilities

Comment: Is 'Charting' a namespace? If so try referencing it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the dll reference to your project?

click on the + next to Reference to see if you have included the correct namespaces/assemblies

Comment: i dont think i need a dll for ms chart, i downaloded and it should have added everything

Comment: you downloaded it but you still need to reference this namespace in your project. Basically the error message is saying that it cannot locate the System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Utilities namespace in your project. Right click on the references folder, click on Add Reference, and locate this namespace (if you had installed it and it was installed into the GAC, it should show up under the .NET tab; otherwise, go to the Browse tab and locate the .dll from there)

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because you've referenced a type with the following name that the compiler cannot find

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Utilities.SampleMain.MainForm
```

The most likely causes for this issue are

1. It exists but it's in a DLL that you haven't referenced in this project.  Check the references of the project and make sure the DLL that contains the type is listed
2. The type name is simply incorrect.  Could be a typo or a just a wrong namespace in the name.

Answer (score 1):

The SampleMain type does not exist in `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Utilities` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Always check that you do not have one of your projects set to the client profile. That will cause this same sort of behavior.